LEFT JOIN и другие
Один из базовых вопросов на собеседованиях: какой максимум строк может вернуть left join при длине таблиц А (2) и Б (3), при каких обстоятельствах.
Ответ известен, прошу толково объяснить, почему именно так.
И вопрос: в каких случаях возникнет cross join?

Какие ещё неоднозначные выводы? Самым тривиальным left join-ом без условия. SELECT A.*, B.* from A LEFT JOIN B; ты получишь декартово произведение строчек. Итого 2 * 3 = 6.

А вот например ответ нейросети:
Минимальное и максимальное количество строк, которые может вернуть оператор left join, зависит от конкретных условий запроса и данных в таблицах. Оператор left join соединяет две таблицы, возвращая все строки из левой таблицы и соответствующие строки из правой таблицы. Если в левой таблице нет соответствующих строк в правой таблице, то оператор left join вернет пустые строки. Максимальное количество строк, которое может вернуть оператор left join, равно сумме строк в обеих таблицах.

Ваша нейросеть галлюцинирует. Просто создайте эти две таблички и напишите запрос выше.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vXxpXxnpcvV9Kma3o5oJSa/0


какой максимум строк может вернуть left join при длине таблиц А (2) и Б (3), при каких обстоятельствах.

Любой JOIN формально обрабатывает все возможные пары записей из таблиц. Если в таблицах 2 и 3 записи, это даёт 6 пар. Соответственно это максимум, который можно получить. И его можно получить при условии, что во всех записях обеих таблиц выражение связи имеет одно и то же значение.
Есть одно исключение. Если при внешнем связывании таблица на внешней стороне не имеет записей (пуста). В этом случае внешнее соединение работает, словно во внешней таблице есть одна запись. Однако это не влияет на именно максимальное количество выходных записей.

в каких случаях возникнет cross join?

Если выражение связывания не использует значений полей связываемых таблиц.
Формально это вроде бы не так, но вопрос предполагает ответ, не зависящий от данных.
